# Routing over different subnets

Tags: centos, routing, firewalld, subnets

I have two subnets `S1 (10.3.0.0/24)` and `S2 (10.3.120.0/24)` and two CentOS 7.6 machines `A` and `B`. Machine `A` two NICs, one for each subnet with ip addresses `10.3.0.4` on `eth0` for `S1` and `10.3.120.254` on `eth1` for `S2`. Machine `B` has only one NIC for Subnet `S2` with the IP `10.3.120.4`. When I ping Machine `A`'s IP address `10.3.120.254` from Machine `B`, I get a response (because they are in the same subnet). But when I ping Machine `A`'s IP `10.3.0.4` from Machine `B`, there is no response.

These are the routes on Machine `A`

```
[me@MachineA ~]$ ip route show
default via 10.3.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.3.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.0.4 metric 100 
10.3.120.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.120.254 metric 101
```

And these are the routes on Machine `B`.

```
[me@MachineB ~]$ ip route show
default via 10.3.120.254 dev eth0 
10.3.120.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.120.4 metric 100
```

Some more information, firewalld is running on Machine `A` but not on Machine `B`. This is the firewalld configuration on Machine `A`.

```
[me@MachineA ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth1 eth0
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: echo-reply
  rich rules:
```

What I wanted to know is what am I missing here? Why is there a response when I ping to `10.3.120.254` but not when I ping `10.3.0.4` although they are two different IP addresses of the same machine and the default  route on Machine `B` should be forwarding the packet to Machine `A`?

**EDIT**: This is the IP setup on Machine `A`.

```
[me@MachineA ~]$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:a3:6f:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.3.0.4/24 brd 10.3.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fea3:6f74/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:09:0a:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.3.120.254/24 brd 10.3.120.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8fd2:7210:82b3:d056/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and this is the IP configuration on Machine `B`

```
[me@MachineB ~]$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:09:38:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.3.120.4/24 brd 10.3.120.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fe09:381f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**EDIT2**: I tried adding the route

```
ip route add 10.3.0.0/24 via 10.3.120.254 dev eth0
```

and it still didn't work

**EDIT3**: I can ping Machine `B` from Machine `A` and packet forwarding is enabled on Machine `A`.

```
[me@MachineA ~]$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Comment: Not familiar with `firewalld`, but `icmp-blocks: echo-reply` will block answers to pings (which is exactly what you are experiencing), and `masquerade: yes` which I assumes means NAT can cause all sort of trouble with routing, depending on what it actually does. Try deactivating the firewall completely and see if it works. If it does, you've found the culprit.

Comment: Well, I cannot deactivate the firewall since I need it to do some basic port forwarding. I tried removing the `icmp-blocks: echo-reply` value but it still does not work.

Comment: You certainly can deactivate the firewall to test if the firewall is the culprit, or if it's anything else. If it turns out to be the firewall, then you've reduced the problem to "how do I configure the firewall to allow port forwarding, but doesn't block things I do need". Debugging works by partitioning the problem until you've found out where it is. "Guessing" doesn't work, you need to test your hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try to add a route to B, which tells B that:

go to subnet 10.3.0.0/24 via 10.3.120.254

Comment: You mean something like `ip route add 10.3.0.0/24 via 10.3.120.254 dev eth0`? I did that and it still does not work.

Comment: You can start a tcpdump on A to see if the specific icmp packet arrives A

Comment: I can see that the ping request arrives at Machine `A`. The tcpdump output contains the following two lines `ARP, Request who-has 10.3.120.4 tell MachineA, length 28` and `ARP, Reply 10.3.120.4 is-at 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (oui Unknown), length 28`. Could the firewall be the one blocking the routing?